How can I run a batch file on macOS?
I've been attempting to install a mod for Elden Ring on Mac, and it uses a batch file to install and launch. I can't seem to get it to run with Wine, receiving these errors:
0074:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\wineusb": c0000142
003c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"wineusb" failed to start: 1114
009c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
009c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
009c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
009c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
00a8:fixme:keyboard:NtUserActivateKeyboardLayout Changing user locale is not supported
00bc:fixme:keyboard:NtUserActivateKeyboardLayout Changing user locale is not supported
Can't recognise 'Play Mod.bat' as an internal or external command, or batch script.

I was wondering if someone knew how to fix this, or the other thing I heard might be possible would be converting the file into a shell script and running that instead? I'm not very versed in this subject, and was wondering if someone could help me with that. Here are the contents of the batch file
@ECHO OFF && TITLE Launch DEN Maps Mod
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%\ModFiles\DenMaps\1.7.0-beta2\PSModInstaller\PlayMod.ps1

@REM if PSModInstaller folder exists, and DenMaps not
IF EXIST "%ThisScriptsDirectory%\PSModInstaller" (
    IF NOT EXIST "%ThisScriptsDirectory%\DenMaps" (
        SET PowerShellScriptPath="%ThisScriptsDirectory%\PSModInstaller\PlayMod.ps1"
    )
)
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'";

I tried to run it using Wine cmd /c "Play Mod.bat" expected it to work, didn't work and gave a bunch of errors instead.
Update: I attempted to run it by starting a new terminal directly from the folder it is in, and it gave me this set of errors
Matthews-Air:1.7.0-beta2 me$ wine cmd /c "Play Mod.bat"
0074:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000142
003c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"wineusb" failed to start: 1114
009c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
009c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
009c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
009c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
00a8:fixme:keyboard:NtUserActivateKeyboardLayout Changing user locale is not supported
00bc:fixme:keyboard:NtUserActivateKeyboardLayout Changing user locale is not supported
0130:fixme:powershell:wmain stub: L"PowerShell" L"-NoProfile" L"-ExecutionPolicy" L"Bypass" L"-Command" L"& 'Z:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\1.7.0-beta2\\\\ModFiles\\DenMaps\\1.7.0-beta2\\PSModInstaller\\PlayMod.ps1';"


Irrespective of your error message and code, you haven't mentioned whether PowerShell is even installed on your Operating System.

Just to be clear, the message displayed has got nothing to do with PowerShell, or really the batch file code. (The message clearly shows at the bottom that it didn't recognize the batch file). So the first thing you should try is using the fully qualified absolute path to the batch file, rather than just its filename.

Have you looked around for how this mod is supposed to be installed for Mac?

I should mention - it's not supposed to be usable on Mac. certainly wasn't designed for it anyways. neither was Elden Ring, but I got that running through GPTK and a couple other shenanigans.

the entirety of the download I am working with can be found at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EVNc2vqUKuvepxllj2ilyz7hlkUC7sNC/view?usp=share_link if that helps anyone

Don't use the batch file at all.  It isn't doing much.
I can't guarantee the next (powershell) step will work, but you don't need the batch file.
This command:   PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'";
Find the DOS LOOKING path to PlayMod.ps1 (from Wine's point of view) and launch powershell directly using the modified above command.
It will be under path the batch file is in.
It will probably look something like:
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "C:\MyCoolModDL\NewEldenRingMod\ModFiles\DenMaps\1.7.0-beta2\PSModInstaller\PlayMod.ps1";
OR
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "C:\MyCoolModDL\NewEldenRingMod\PSModInstaller\PlayMod.ps1;
Better still.. look for a mac solution as @music2myear hinted at..

tried this, the console just turns into an > on the next line. not quite sure what that means, I dont have a lot of experience in this.

Sorry.. it didn't help @matthewkuni

no worries, thanks for trying.
